# how to set padding to the left on a drawable

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a drawable that  I would like to programmatically set to the left please advise on how I can go about doing this . Below is the drawable  as it is in my code

```
 getBar().setLogo(R.drawable.ic_barIcon);
```

and this is how I am trying to pad it at the moment

```
txtVw.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.ic_deviceinsight_actionbar, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Programmatically set to the left of what?